# How to set values as empty in dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I tried to set some values in a dataframe to empty based on a condition in python. The code is something like this,

```
df.loc[df['Col1'] > 0.5, 'Col2'] = np.nan
```

However, in output file (.csv), it's "nan" there. So wondering if there are any ways to make it empty? Thanks.

Comment: What do you define as an empty value? Just an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['Col1'] > 0.5, 'Col2'] = ""
```

... will give you an empty value of type string. If you export your DataFrame to a .csv file, you will get an empty value.

Comment: This will change the data type of the columns

Comment: @the_ordinary_guy true, but most likely won't matter if OP exports it to CSV. If it does, then don't use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

After your step:

```
df = df.loc[df['Col1'] > 0.5, 'Col2'] = np.nan
```

fill `NaN`s with empty string and write to csv

```
df = df.fillna("")
```